# How to easily develop desktop widgets compatible with iOS and Android in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, android-widget

I'm developing an application using Flutter, and I need to implement some desktop widget functionality, such as control buttons for a music player. I want these widgets to be displayed on the device's home screen and accessible even when the app is in the background. I heard that Flutter itself doesn't support this type of widget development, and it needs to be implemented using native platform code. I'm wondering if there are any plugins available to improve the development efficiency in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for Home Screen widgets? If yes, this package should be a good starting point

https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget